# Parent-child shared buffer overflow in c

Tags: c, process, operating-system, shared-memory, mmap

I am trying to create a shared buffer using mmap. The code is supposed to output a mandelbrot set using processes to compute each line. Each process that computes a line proceeds to store it in a shared buffer and then we have to output the buffer to stdout. However I have noticed that the buffer gets filled correctly inside thread func, but when I try to print the buffer in main() half of it is overflowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
/*TODO header file for m(un)map*/

#include "mandel-lib.h"

#define MANDEL_MAX_ITERATION 100000

/***************************
 * Compile-time parameters *
 ***************************/
int N;
volatile int *shared_buff;
/*
 * Output at the terminal is is x_chars wide by y_chars long
*/
int y_chars = 50;
int x_chars = 90;

/*
 * The part of the complex plane to be drawn:
 * upper left corner is (xmin, ymax), lower right corner is (xmax, ymin)
*/
double xmin = -1.8, xmax = 1.0;
double ymin = -1.0, ymax = 1.0;
    
/*
 * Every character in the final output is
 * xstep x ystep units wide on the complex plane.
 */
double xstep;
double ystep;

int safe_atoi(char *s){
    long l;
    char *endp;
    l = strtol(s,&endp,10);
    if(s != endp && *endp == '\0'){
        return l;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}



/*
 * This function computes a line of output
 * as an array of x_char color values.
 */
void compute_mandel_line(int line, int color_val[])
{
    /*
     * x and y traverse the complex plane.
     */
    double x, y;

    int n;
    int val;
    /* Find out the y value corresponding to this line */
    y = ymax - ystep * line;

    /* and iterate for all points on this line */
    for (x = xmin, n = 0; n < x_chars; x+= xstep, n++) {

        /* Compute the point's color value */
        val = mandel_iterations_at_point(x, y, MANDEL_MAX_ITERATION);
        if (val > 255)
            val = 255;

        /* And store it in the color_val[] array */
        val = xterm_color(val);
        color_val[n] = val;
    }

}

/*
 * This function outputs an array of x_char color values
 * to a 256-color xterm.
 */
void output_mandel_line(int line,volatile int buff[], int color_val[])
{
    int i;
    
    char point ='@';
    char newline='\n';

    for (i = 0; i < x_chars; i++) {
        /* Set the current color, then output the point */
        buff[i+x_chars*line] = color_val[i];
        /* code for testing buffer line 40:
        if(line==40) printf("buff:%d color: %d",buff[i+x_chars*line],color_val[i]); */  
    }
    
    //printf("Line %d write to buffer\n",line);
}

void compute_and_output_mandel_line(volatile int buff[], int line)
{
    /*
     * A temporary array, used to hold color values for the line being drawn
     */
    int color_val[x_chars];

    compute_mandel_line(line, color_val);
    output_mandel_line(line,buff, color_val);
}




void child_func(int arg, volatile int buff[]){

    int color_val[x_chars];
    volatile long int i;
    size_t proc_num = (size_t)arg;
    for(i = proc_num; i < y_chars; i += N){
        
        compute_mandel_line(i,color_val);
        output_mandel_line(i,buff,color_val);

        /* code for testing if line 40 of the buffer is filled:
            if(i==40){
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<x_chars;j++){
                printf("buffer: %d", buff[j+x_chars*40]);
            }
        }
       */

    }
    printf("process %d exiting\n",proc_num);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int line;
    xstep = (xmax - xmin) / x_chars;
    ystep = (ymax - ymin) / y_chars;
    N = safe_atoi(argv[1]);
    if(N < 1){
        perror("invalid num of threads");
        exit(1);
    }   
    size_t i;
    shared_buff = mmap(NULL,y_chars*x_chars,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANON,-1,0); 

    pid_t *pids = malloc(N* sizeof(*pids));
    if(pids == NULL){
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(1);

    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){

        pids[i] = fork();
        printf("%d\n",pids[i]);
        if(pids[i] < 0){
            perror("err");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pids[i] == 0){
            child_func(i,shared_buff);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    
    /*int j;
    for(j=0;j<x_chars;j++) printf("buffer received: %d",shared_buff[j+x_chars*40]);
    */
    char point = '@';
    char newline = '\n';

    for (line = 0; line<y_chars; line++){
        for (i = 0; i<x_chars; i++){
            set_xterm_color(1, shared_buff[i+line*x_chars]);
        
        if (write(1, &point, 1) != 1) {
            perror("compute_and_output_mandel_line: write point");
            exit(1);
        }
        }   

    // Now that the line is done, output a newline character 
        if (write(1, &newline, 1) != 1) {
            perror("compute_and_output_mandel_line: write newline");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    reset_xterm_color(1);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have something named `thrd_func` which isn't a thread callback? I'm not making any sense of this. Do you mean to use threads or not? fork() doesn't create threads, it spawns processes.

Comment: @Lundin you are right sorry for the confusion, the past implementations were with threads instead of processes so I forgot to change the name, I edited my code and added a more appropriate name

Comment: "half of it is overflowed". What does that mean? What is the exact expected output and actual output? But for starters the parent process creates all the children and then immediately tries to print the results instead of waiting for the children to complete their tasks first.